# Django auth inbuilt view cannot recognize my customized html file

Tags: django, authentication

I am trying to use django's inbuilt urls and views for the user authentication but have customized the html files, e.g. login.html registration/password_reset_form.html

I have imported the urls in my url.py

```
from django.contrib.auth import urls
```

and in the urlpatterns

```
url(r'^account/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
```

in my views.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import *
```

(with no other view functions to handle the auth process)

in my `registration` file there are `login.html` `password_reset_form.html` `password_reset_done.html`...

The problem is that the django view login is recognizing my login.html under the registration file as it shows my customized log in page, but for the url `account/password_reset/` the django password_reset view function cannot recongnize my `password_reset_form.html`, instead, it is using the django password_reset page.

Can anyone tell me where the problem could be and how to solve this problem?
I have read the django auth codes here https://github.com/django/django/tree/master/django/contrib/auth
  and really want to use the django inbuilt url/views to make my project standard. Thank you very much.

Comment: Did you add the location of `registration/` as a template location?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams oh,yea,thank you, that's where I think might be the problem but dun know how..So in the settings.py TEMPLATE_DIRS ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [filesystem template loader](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#template-loaders) uses [`settings.TEMPLATE_DIRS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#template-dirs) to specify where to look for templates, so make sure that you've added the directory containing `registration/` to it (and that you've enabled the filesystem loader).

Comment: Hi, I import os using 'import os' and then in the settings added 'TEMPLATE_DIRS = (os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..', 'AppName', 'templates'),)'  Now its recognizing, thank you so much!